# Is there a way to optimize the following Python 3 code block?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization, large-data

```
# "List" is an empty Pandas DataFrame with the same length of
# "Tab_B" DataFrame to be filled in the following code.
# After its creation, I append it to "Tab_B" as a new column.
# The filling is done by searching for a value in another DataFrame ("DF1").
# This search, in turn, uses Pandas "at", by label indexing
# (the labels are values in each "Tab_B" row - namely,
# "Fields '0', '1' and '2'"). I hope I've been clear enough.

List = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column_Name'])

for x in range(len(Tab_B)):
    List.loc[x] = DF1.at[Tab_B['Field_2'].loc[x],Tab_B['Field_0'].loc[x]] - DF1.at[Tab_B['Field_1'].loc[x],Tab_B['Field_0'].loc[x]]
    
Tab_B['Column_Name'] = List
del List
```

Problem is, Tab_B is a 3,5 million rows DataFrame. The code I'm running is twice this code I wrote above, and it has been running for 4 hours now. :(

I'm rather new to Python coding, and the code is simple enough, so I'm not acquainted with optimization techniques, and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: provide [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and desired output

Comment: I'm not exactly new to programming, I've been doing a lot of coding during and since college. Python, in particular, I just know enough to code according to my needs. When I was searching for optimization tips, I came by "vectorization", but indeed I couln't understand it well. If you have any article that could make me learn the basic idea and operation, I would appreciate.

Comment: As for MRE, I'll try to provide when possible.

Comment: If you code works, it might be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: I just updated the case in the comments to the answer. I implemented what seems to me to be a vectorization technique, and indeed it improved the performance of my script, but not enough to reduce the time to less than two hours (maybe I was being too optimistic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectorized operations, which are generally faster and more efficient in Pandas.

Here's how you can optimize your code:

First, create a MultiIndex DataFrame from `DF1` using `set_index` method. This allows you to perform label-based indexing more efficiently.

```
DF1_multiindex = DF1.set_index(['Field_0', 'Field_1'])
```

Next, use the `lookup` function to create a new column in `Tab_B`. The `lookup` function takes two arrays of labels and returns the corresponding values from the DataFrame.

```
Tab_B['Column_Name'] = DF1_multiindex.lookup(Tab_B['Field_0'], Tab_B['Field_1']) - DF1_multiindex.lookup(Tab_B['Field_2'], Tab_B['Field_0'])
```

This should be significantly faster because it avoids the use of a for loop and takes advantage of Pandas' built-in vectorized operations.

**EDIT 1:**

1. For more optimization, use `query` instead of `lookup`: The `query` function in `pandas` is faster than `lookup` because it uses the `numexpr` library, which can evaluate expressions more quickly. However, you'll need to create a new DataFrame that contains the values you want to look up, and then use query to find the corresponding values. Here's how you can do it:

   ```
   Tab_B['Column_Name'] = DF1_multiindex.query('Field_0 == @Tab_B["Field_0"] and Field_1 == @Tab_B["Field_1"]') - DF1_multiindex.query('Field_0 == @Tab_B["Field_2"] and Field_1 == @Tab_B["Field_0"]')
   ```

note: `@` is used to reference variables in the query string

2. Avoid creating unnecessary copies of DataFrames: When you perform operations on DataFrames, `pandas` often creates a copy of the DataFrame in memory. This can significantly slow down your code and increase memory usage. To avoid this, you can use the `inplace` parameter to modify the DataFrame in place, or use the view method to return a view on the DataFrame's data.

Comment: As soon as possible I'll try to implement your suggestion. Thank you! I'll be back here to tell you what happened.

Comment: Did it work for what you needed?

Comment: I implemented that and, in a small sample test, the running time decreased from 9s to 6s. Unfortunately, for the complete database, it's still taking a lot of time. I find it puzzling that, say, the execution time for the 9.2k rows sample is about 6s, but though a proportional estimation results in about 45 minutes for the 3.6M rows DB, it's actually taking way more than that time to run (I don't know the exact time because I just killed the process after 4 hours). 

What's interesting too is that in a ~450k rows sample, it took about 40 minutes to run.

Comment: I must add I didn't use 'lookup' because Pandas Documentation said it is deprecated. So I  kept using 'loc'. Also, maybe I was being too optimistic in hoping I could reduce the total running time to less than 2 hours.  I think I'll just break it down to smaller bases, that shoud do it for now.

Comment: Do you think there is more I could to reduce execution time? Anyways, I'm really grateful for the help, it was a significant improve in performance.

Comment: I mean, I'm not exactly an expert in python, I know maybe two other things that could improve performance, however I don't know to what extent the improvement will be (added to the answer in an edit). At some point, I would just consider changing to a more performant programming language. But I know that is not exactly a solution. PS. Consider maybe cython? Might worth a look.

Comment: In my research, I came across "Cython" but I didn't know what it mean (so I just ignored it). I just read it is something libe working in C in Python. It sounds indeed an interesting way to go. Thanks for the suggestion. I will probably take some time to get into it, but since I've worked with the basics of C before, it must not be an impossible task. Again, thanks for the suggestion.